# What's the correct way to %-hex encode a URI?

Tags: java, http

I've created a basic server using Java servlets. What I'd like to do is implement a more liberal URI syntax by allowing non-alphanumeric characters in the URI's as long as they are %-hex encoded i.e two words.txt could be encoded as two%words.txt.

I'm not sure how to go about this. I've tried using java's .replace in the form of uri.replace(' ', '%') but this gives me a message format exception.

Comment: I strongly advice to use the defined URL encoding instead of inventing your own.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

```
String encoded = URLEncoder.encode("This string has spaces", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: I'm still getting an MessageFormatException when trying to run PUT test text.txt HTTP/1.1 - is there something I'm missing? i tried to encode my URI after parsing it.

Comment: have you tried to begin the URI with a `/`? How do you send the request?

Comment: I just tried with a '/' but no luck. This is how I encode:
RequestMessage reqMsg = RequestMessage.parse(is);
                // gets the uri from the parsed request message
                uri = reqMsg.getURI();
                String encodedUri = URLEncoder.encode(uri, "UTF-8");

And how I request: PUT /test spaces.txt HTTP/1.1

Comment: I guess you need to put the encoded URI in the request and decode it after the request is parsed...

Comment: So it was proven to me that the client is responsible to properly encode the request URI. That means that you need to, like I stated above, encode the URI from your client, before sending the request (=> HTTP spec), and after receiving the request, decode the URI again.